# Histogram normalization in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Give a dataframe

```
x <- runif(1000, 0, 10)
y <- c(rep("success", 500), rep("failure", 500))
z <- data.frame(x, y)
```

is it possible to generate a histogram similar to

```
ggplot(z, aes(x, fill = y)) + geom_histogram()
```

but with *..count..* normalized to

*attempts = success + failure*

in each bin using ggplot? Many thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**
Many thanks for all response!! Sorry I think I've oversimplified the question I have. A dataframe that's much closer to the data I'm working with is

```
df <- data.frame(
v1 = runif(128000, 0, 10),
v2 = factor(rep(rep(1:5, c(1,10,8,4,2)), 5120)),
v3 = factor(rep(rep(1:12, c(2,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6)), 2000)),
v4 = c(rep("success", 64000), rep("failure", 64000)))
```

just that the data are not as evenly distributed. With the aim of finding certain patterns between the v1-v4, I'm visually exploring these data e.g. by

```
ggplot(df, aes(v1, fill = v2)) +
geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.2, position = "stack") +
facet_wrap("v3")
```

and

```
ggplot(df %>% filter(v4 == "success"), aes(v1, fill = v2)) +
geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.2, position = "stack") +
facet_wrap("v3")
```

Based on what I've seen so far, I'd now like to take this one step further by normalizing the ..count.. in the last plot, i.e. successes or failures, to the total amount of attempts in each bin, i.e. attempts = (successes + failures), to get some sort of frequency plot. For example in v3 facet x, v2 group y, v1 bin z I'd like to see 0.25 (from 100 successes / 400 attempts) instead of 100 successes.

**EDIT 2:**
The plot I have in mind looks like this:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(v1_bins = cut(v1, breaks = 5))

df_successes <- df %>% group_by(v1_bins, v2, v3, v4) %>% 
filter(v4 == "success") %>% summarise(successes = n()) %>% 
ungroup() %>% select(-v4)

df_attempts <- df %>% group_by(v1_bins, v2, v3) %>% 
summarise(attempts = n()) %>% ungroup()

df_freq <- left_join(df_attempts, df_successes, by = c("v1_bins", "v2", "v3")) %>% 
mutate(success_freq = successes / attempts)
```

which plots

```
ggplot(df_freq, aes(x = v1_bins, y = success_freq, group = v2)) +
geom_col(aes(fill = v2), position = "identity", alpha = "0.5") +
facet_wrap("v3")
```

or

```
ggplot(df_freq, aes(x = v1_bins, y = success_freq, group = v2)) +
geom_line(aes(colour = v2)) +
facet_wrap("v3")
```

Comment: Can you explain your expected output? What do you mean by _"normalized"_? From what I can tell, your plot is stacked, so it already shows `success + failure` in each bin.

Comment: Yes, that correct. In the real-life dataset I use other factors for stacking and faceting and I'd therefore like to plot 'successes/attempts' or 'failures/attempts' grouped by those factors. Sorry for the imprecision; does this make more sense?

Comment: Do you mean create a separate facet of success/failure histogram for each group? In that case, I suggest you add a `group` column to your sample data to better reflect your real dataset

Comment: I've added an edit to my posted question because I think I've over-simplified it. Hope that anyone's still with me.

Comment: I don't understand what more you need - the existing answer already points you with what to do with your new data. Just replace `geom_histogram(position = "stack")` with `geom_bar(position = "fill")`

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking to get the proportion success and failures in each bin of the histogram. One way to do this would be to create cut points on the data and do a bar chart with `position = "fill"`

```
z %>% 
  mutate(bins = cut(x, breaks = 30)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(bins, fill = y)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = .5))
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
Based on your edits, it appears that you are trying to get the proportion of successes for each combination of `binned_v1`, `v2` and `v3`. Starting with your data, the following chart shows these. It is pretty busy. I decreased the bins to 10 because 30 was too much to look at.

```
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = runif(128000, 0, 10),
  v2 = factor(rep(rep(1:5, c(1,10,8,4,2)), 5120)),
  v3 = factor(rep(rep(1:12, c(2,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6)), 2000)),
  v4 = c(rep("success", 64000), rep("failure", 64000)))

df %>% 
  mutate(bins = cut(v1, breaks = 10)) %>% 
  group_by(bins, v2, v3) %>% 
  summarise(success_prop = mean(v4 == "success")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(bins, success_prop, fill = v2)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = .5)) +
  facet_wrap(~ v3)
```

Comment: A bar chart is not a histogram. Maybe this is what OP wants (its hard to know for sure from the question), but its not what was requested

Comment: I've added an edit to my posted question because I think I've over-simplified it. What I really need to plot on y is the success or failure rate (i.e. successes / attempts or failure / attempts) which a bar chart only allows for a very simple case.

Comment: I am not sure I am understanding. The bar in the above graph is showing success / attempts (blue) and failures / attempts (red) for each bin of the x variable. For example, lets say that there are 30 attempts in the first bin (.0326,.0347]. Lets say that there are 13 success out of these 30 attempts. The blue portion of the bar shows that the proportion of successes in this range of x is .43. The proportion of failures for this same range is 1 - .43 = .57.

Comment: Yes, understood. In this case that's a solution. But if the plot is grouped already by another variable **v2**, overlaying another grouping by success/failure will prevent reading out the fraction of successes (see edit 2 above for what plot I have in mind).